# Adding JPanel Object into a separate JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm working on a menu, I want to make it as object orientated as possible so I've made a separate class for the menu JPanel object. The problem is that it doesn't want to add it to my main JPanel. What am I doing wrong and how should I fix it?

**Main Class:**

```
package StackOverflow;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();
    private CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    private GamePanel gp = new GamePanel();

    public Main(){
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.setSize(1200, 700);
        frame.setTitle("Rain | Pre-Alpha");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MainPanel.setLayout(cl);

        MainPanel.add(gp, "1");

        frame.add(MainPanel);

        cl.show(MainPanel, "1");

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

**GamePanel Class:**

```
package StackOverflow;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel {
    private JPanel GamePanel = new JPanel();

    public GamePanel(){
        GamePanel.setBackground(Color.green);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a class to your `JFrame`, JFrame accept `Component` :

```
public Component add(Component comp, int index)
```

So you have many ways to solve your problem :

## Option 1

Extends `JPanel` instead  :

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    public GamePanel() {
        super.setBackground(Color.green);
    }
}
```

## Option 2

You can use getters and setters :

```
public class GamePanel {

    private JPanel GamePanel = new JPanel();

    public JPanel getGamePanel() {
        return GamePanel;
    }

    public void setGamePanel(JPanel GamePanel) {
        this.GamePanel = GamePanel;
    }

    public GamePanel() {
        GamePanel.setBackground(Color.green);
    }

}
```

and you can add your JPanel like this :

```
MainPanel.add(gp.getGamePanel(), "1");
```